# Wordpress behind a load balancer and CDN does not update CSS immediately

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, caching, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-cdn

The CSS does not update immediately when the website is accessed via the domain. It is updated immediately when accessed via the VM's IP.

How can I configure the CDN to immediately update the cache content whenever there is a change in CSS?

**Set Up**

- Bitnami WordPress
- Google Load Balancer
- CDN enabled

**Enqueue CSS in WordPress**

`function wpscripts() { wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/styles.css', array(), '1.0.0' ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpscripts' );`

**This is my CDN setting**
[image]

[image]

Comment: You do not modify JS and CSS files in place for a deployed website. You change the file names. There are many strategies, common ones are a date, version, or hash value. Your problem is not only with a CDN but with web browsers that also cache objects.

Comment: I tried invalidating css and also versioning but it doesn't work in my case. Clueless why. Web browser cache is forced cleared and each time it keeps retrieving different versions of old CSS. Also when I access the css directly with a hyperlink, it shows the latest version on the server.

Comment: Use the CLI `curl` with the -v option: `curl -v -L example.com`. You can see the headers which will show you the dates and cache settings for the file. Are you using a WordPress cache plugin? If yes, flush its cache. Remember, flushing your browser cache will have zero impact on other users' browsers. Version your files and solve your problems (plural) in one step.

Comment: Invalidations cycle time on Cloud CDN are not an instant purge like some other CDNs in the market. The p90 for invalidation is about 2 minutes; however, it can take up to 10 minutes to fully process across the entire platform. There is work underway to reduce this cycle time, but there is no announced date for release at this time. John's suggestion of changing date or versioning is a good approach in you want "instant" updates.

Comment: @JohnHanley As far as I know, this snippet that I used supposed to version the files `function wpscripts() { wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/styles.css', array(), '1.0.0' ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpscripts' );` however, it doesn't clear the CDN cache. I didn't have this issue until recently, I wonder if is because of any change in CDN.

Comment: @Dave I have tried invalidating cache for that specific file but still doesn't work. It is still using the older version instead of the latest version.

Comment: I have given you the tools to diagnose the problem. By using them you will develop a better understanding of your problem. Ignore them and you will continue to state that you do not understand. There is no magic to your problem. Everyone who develops websites will experience this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The main purpose of a CDN is to cache your content at the edge as close as possible to your end users.

Looking at your settings it will stay there up to 6 months.

You can turn off the CDN option, evaluate the possibility to invalidate the caches, give your script a new name each time you update it.

*** edit: I'm adding details as apparently my previous answer was not clear enough.

1/ The easiest way, especially if you don't understand fully the CDN mechanics is to turn it off, you will always fetch the latest version of your content.

2/ If your content does not evolve too often you could ask the CDN to invalidate its cache
(Google CDN is offering the option, check https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content).

3/ You can version your content, a new version will get a new URL, the cache will not contain this version and will fetch it from the origin.
For instance the `wp_enqueue_style` function you are using accepts a `ver` parameter.
This parameter if provided is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes (as described here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).
Looking at your CDN settings your cache key includes query strings so will take into account this version number.

Comment: thanks but none works in my case. I tried invalidating css and also versioning but it doesn't work in my case. I've forced clear browser cache and with each refresh, it will retrieve older versions of css inconsistently. When I access the css directly with a hyperlink, it shows the latest version on the server.

Comment: Please add more details, describe step by step your testing procedure for 3/ you could also capture the http request and headers returned by the cdn for your css file